# android.view.InflateException in android-swipelistview

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i am using [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) library. I am getting error

```
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.emr/com.example.emr.EmrLauncher}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.example.emr.EmrLauncher.onCreate(EmrLauncher.java:59)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    ... 11 more
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    ... 23 more
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "@2131427340"
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView.init(SwipeListView.java:164)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    at com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView.<init>(SwipeListView.java:134)
04-12 12:53:47.189: E/AndroidRuntime(15197):    ... 26 more
```

This is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.emr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".EmrLauncher" >

    <com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/Location"
        android:id="@+id/emrlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        app:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
        app:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        app:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
        app:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        app:swipeMode="both"
        app:swipeOffsetLeft="40dp"
        app:swipeOffsetRight="40dp"
        app:swipeOpenOnLongPress="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using actionbar sherlock library too. I have added all necessary attr for swipelistview.Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure but change namespace to    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: @Manoj did you get any solution for the issue

Comment: @Manoj did you got any solution to this problem

Comment: @Manoj did you find any solution to this crashy crash?

Comment: @Dittimon I copied his package to my project and copied resources too.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve this satisfactorily using the swipelistview jar in libs/, so I simply linked to the source as an external library project, and that worked fine.

You'll need something like this in your project's project.properties (assumes your build environment uses ant - if not, there are similar methods for eclipse):

```
android.library.reference.1=../ThirdParty/android-swipelistview
```

I suspect the problem with the jar approach is that the swipe list initializer has no access to your project's resources at compile time, so things get messed up when it tries to pull in those resources (from your local attrs.xml file) - the references don't point to /your/ resources, because when the jar is compiled, those resources don't exist.

Anyway, hope this helps get things moving.

Answer (score 0):

check my post on getting started with swipelistview: http://modewagon.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/getting-started-with-swipelistview/